# Same datatype multiple variable declaration in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables

in objective-c we can declare variable like
-`NSString *a,*b,*c;`

in swift there a way to declare same datatype multiple variable variable rather than doing like below

```
var a: NSString = ""
var b: NSString = ""
var c: NSString = ""
```

So, is it possible to declare all a,b,c variable into one line like
`var (a,b,c): a:NSstring=("","","")` or something?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> You can declare multiple constants or multiple variables on a single
>   line, separated by commas:
>
> ```
> var a = "", b = "", c = ""
> ```
>
> NOTE
>
> If a stored value in your code is not going to change, always declare
>   it as a constant with the let keyword. Use variables only for storing
>   values that need to be able to change.

**Type Annotations:**

> You can define multiple related variables of the same type on a single
>   line, separated by commas, with a single type annotation after the
>   final variable name:
>
> ```
> var red, green, blue: Double
> ```
>
> NOTE
>
> It is rare that you need to write type annotations in practice. If you
>   provide an initial value for a constant or variable at the point that
>   it is defined, Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for
>   that constant or variable, as described in Type Safety and Type
>   Inference.

Documentation [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: I want to initialize `var taxableIncome, taxBeforeCess, taxAfterCess: Double` this value all at once. What will be syntax? I tried multiple things, but none worked.

Answer (score 10):

Swift has an odd design decision here. Placing a type on a variable affects all previous non-explicitly typed variables in a multi-line definition. Same for constants.

These two lines are equivalent (a, b and c are Double):

```
var a, b, c: Double
var a: Double, b: Double, c: Double
```

And these two are equivalent (a and b are Int, while c and d are Double):

```
var a, b: Int, c, d: Double
var a: Int, b: Int, c: Double, d: Double
```