# Is it possible to declare variable in one line in swift?

Tags: swift

I Have declared variable in one line in swift but it shows error

```
 var intQ,intDL,intDN,intPN,intA : Int
```

[image: error image]

Is it possible to declare the same type variables in one line in swift?

Comment: Documentation here : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390934/same-datatype-multiple-variable-declaration-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible inside a **struct**

```
struct Foo {
    var intQ,intDL,intDN,intPN,intA : Int
}
```

and to create an instance with

```
let foo = Foo(intQ: 0, intDL: 1, intDN: 2, intPN: 3, intA: 4)
```

---

Inside a **class** you have to add an initializer – regardless if you declare one or more properties in one line – or you have to add initial values which is also possible in one line

```
class Foo {
    var intQ = 0, intDL = 1, intDN = 2, intPN = 3, intA = 4
}
```

In both struct and class you can declare multiple (local) variables of the same type in one line inside a method if it's guaranteed that they are initialized in the scope of the method.